# Having some trouble with boost in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, boost

When I use boost ,I have some trouble.It can run in mobile phone,but not iphone simulator.This is some error message.

ld: in /Users/7road/Documents/sdk/libboost_system.a(error_code.o), building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file built for OSX, for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

I use 'otool -lv libboost_system.a' to find some message. It don't have LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONES. But I don't know how to solve it.Please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Xcode 7 you have to specify the target for the architecture library. These commands have to be passed in the compilation:

iOS Device Target:

```
-miphoneos-version-min=7.0
```

I have an updated boost library that works with the latest Xcode here:

- It currently has arm64, armv7, i386, x86_64
- Boost 1.59.0 or previous
- libc++ / std=c++11 -- Now optional release for libstdc++
- Precompiled and Script to build yourself (so if you need libstdc++ quite easy to change)

  - Supports Xcode 7

[https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost][1]